# AWT container layout

Tags: java, awt, layout-manager

I have a quite simple question about laying out components in Java AWT program here.

What I want to achieve is, to set the background of the application to a specified image (from file systenm) and add a button on the UI.

What I have is

```
package javaapplication2;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.util.HashSet;


public class JavaApplication2 extends Frame {
private Container gui;
private Button b;
public JavaApplication2() {
    setSize(400,400); // set size to 400x400

    gui = new Container() { // my own container that may write string (or draw image in the future)
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.setFont(new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 48));
            g.setColor(new Color(10,10,10));
            g.fillRect(20, 20, getWidth()-40, getHeight()-40);
            g.setColor(new Color(24, 89, 245));
            g.drawString("hello", 200,200);
        }
    };

    // create a button
    b = new Button("bu");
    // add the button into the container?
    gui.add(b);
    b.setVisible(true);

    // add gui into the root container
    add(gui);
    gui.setSize(400, 400);
    //gui.setVisible(true);  
    validate();
} 

public static void main(String[] args) {
   // TODO code application logic heren
    JavaApplication2 a = new JavaApplication2();
    a.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Then when I ran it, all I could see is black background (color(10,10,10)) and text "hello". I guess that's because although b is added into the container, the paint is called so the whole container is painted so I can't see the button.

I guess there should be some simple solution and hope someone can help me with it.

Comment: `g.fillRect(20, 20, getWidth()-40, getHeight()-40);` is painting over the top of the children.  Is there any reason you're using AWT?

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer. Actually I'm learning to code with BD-J which is based on MHP on top of Java ME. Only 4 awt classes are available to use. This piece of code is copied from an example for MHP. I tried to substitute Container with Panel, then got what I want. But awt.Panel is not available in MHP. So I'll try other ways. Thanks anyway

Comment: AWT components don't really have a concept of "background", so you might find this really difficult....